# Can something 'refrain' you from doing something?

Tags: grammar, verbs

One of the definitions of the verb *refrain* is...

> [refrain](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/refrain_1?q=refrain) - *to avoid doing or **stop yourself** from doing something.*

If there's **an external force of your own(!)** that *stops* you from doing something, how the word *refrain* is used?

Is this sentence correct?

> "Your **own** baseless ethics! Yes, that's what stops yourself from doing that work."

The ethics are mine and so I, myself, cannot overcome them. So, here, it happens to me, myself.

This sentence throws error but...

> "Your **own** baseless ethics! Yes, that's what *refrains* you from doing that work."

Comment: I think we shouldn't and probably can't use *refrain* transitively (e.g. \*"He refrained you").

Answer (score 2):

Your example is incorrect because *your ethics* is not the same as *yourself*, regardless of ownership. Even though values are an integral part of defining a person, they are not the same. An individual might change and is more than their ethics, and the same morals may be held by multiple people. You've suggested this yourself by acknowledging *ethics* as an *external force*.

*Refrain* is a reflexive verb and used intransitively. The definition encapsulates a patient already; the agent always holds back or stops itself. One never *refrains* something else, and we typically don't say *I refrained myself* because that's redundant. Note that *I refrained myself* is not really a transitive usage; it's an explicit statement of the complete reflexive meaning.

Archaically, *refrain* was used transitively as a synonym for *restrain* (meaning you could *refrain someone else*, not just yourself), but this usage has been dropped from modern English and is no longer correct.

I suggest using *restrain* for transitive cases such as your sample sentence.